# rabbitmq - erlang client integration with ejabberd module

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, ejabberd

I currently using `rabbit_client` to send queue message from our ejabberd. This message is triggered using ejabberd hook. Can successfully compiled and installed without any issue.

I keep on getting the same error when the try to create the connection. Appreciated if someone could give some clue on the issue.

Following is the code used to connect and publish the message.

```
{ok, Connection} =
    amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{host = "192.168.xx.xx", username = "username", password= "password"}),
{ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),

amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"hello">>}),

amqp_channel:cast(Channel,
                  #'basic.publish'{
                    exchange = <<"">>,
                    routing_key = <<"hello">>},
                  #amqp_msg{payload = <<"Hello World!">>}),
io:format(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'~n"),
ok = amqp_channel:close(Channel),
ok = amqp_connection:close(Connection),
ok.
```

**Error**

> {undef,[{amqp_connection,start,[{amqp_params_network,"username","password",<<"/">>,"192.168.xx.xx",undefined,0,0,10,infinity,none,[#Fun,#Fun],[],[]}],[]},{mod_mymod,send_internal_notice,4,[{file,"src/mod_mymod.erl"},{line,67}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,382}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,329}]},{ejabberd_c2s,presence_update,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,2068}]},{ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,1249}]},{p1_fsm,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm.erl"},{line,582}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}

Answer (score 2):

`{undef,[{amqp_connection,start,...` means that the `amqp_connection:start/1` function was not defined (`undef`). This usually means that the `amqp_connection` module isn't in the Erlang code path.

Comment: Thanks @Roger for the hint. Really appreciate it.

Comment: for someone that having the same issue, in order to resolve this you need to put rabbit_client and amqp_common into $ejabberd/lib directory. Download link : http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-erlang-client/